# Using Let's Encrypt inside Docker's official Wordpress container

Tags: wordpress, docker, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to get Let's Encrypt *inside* the official Docker Wordpress container.

## Setup the environment

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
wordpress:
  hostname: some.fqdn.com
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443

db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
$ docker exec -ti root_wordpress_1 bash
```

## Install Let's Encrypt

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y git-core
[...]
$ cd /usr/local
$ git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
[...] 
$ cd letsencrypt/
$ ./letsencrypt-auto --apache
Checking for new version...
Requesting root privileges to run letsencrypt...
   /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt --apache
An unexpected error occurred:
PythonDialogBug
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

## More logs

```
$ cat /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2016-03-04 15:28:41,551:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Root logging level set at 30
2016-03-04 15:28:41,553:INFO:letsencrypt.cli:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
2016-03-04 15:28:41,554:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:letsencrypt version: 0.4.2
2016-03-04 15:28:41,554:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Arguments: ['--apache']
2016-03-04 15:28:41,555:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#apache,PluginEntryPoint#webroot,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#standalone)
2016-03-04 15:28:41,559:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Requested authenticator apache and installer apache
2016-03-04 15:28:42,166:DEBUG:letsencrypt.display.ops:Single candidate plugin: * apache
Description: Apache Web Server - Alpha
Interfaces: IAuthenticator, IInstaller, IPlugin
Entry point: apache = letsencrypt_apache.configurator:ApacheConfigurator
Initialized: <letsencrypt_apache.configurator.ApacheConfigurator object at 0x7fd05eb85310>
Prep: True
2016-03-04 15:28:42,168:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Selected authenticator <letsencrypt_apache.configurator.ApacheConfigurator object at 0x7fd05eb85310> and installer <letsencrypt_apache.configurator.ApacheConfigurator object at 0x7fd05eb85310>
2016-03-04 15:28:42,178:DEBUG:letsencrypt.cli:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/letsencrypt/cli.py", line 1993, in main
    return config.func(config, plugins)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/letsencrypt/cli.py", line 658, in run
    domains = _find_domains(config, installer)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/letsencrypt/cli.py", line 133, in _find_domains
    domains = display_ops.choose_names(installer)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/letsencrypt/display/ops.py", line 217, in choose_names
    default=True)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/letsencrypt/display/util.py", line 156, in yesno
    yes_label=yes_label, no_label=no_label)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dialog.py", line 3749, in yesno
    kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dialog.py", line 1765, in _widget_with_no_output
    widget_name, output))
PythonDialogBug
```

Anyone got any clues here?

I want to build an image on top of the official Wordpress image that automatically adds Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this could be the issue with `TERM`, because the client uses some  terminal user interface[image],
but even after fixing this with `export TERM=xterm`, you'll hit the issue with apache restart, when the letsencrypt client restarts apache and the wordpress container has been killed immediately. Thanks to the answer [How to automatically start a service when running a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container) I've overcome this in my [custom WordPress image](https://github.com/vitr/docker-letsencrypt-wordpress) with the tail approach, you can have a look for more ideas there, as you can see from the screenshot, it works))

**update**

the following steps help to fix the issue with lines in the dialog (in addition to previously applied `export TERM=xterm`)

```
apt-get install locales
locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
```

[image]

You can also run the client in 2 other modes

- `-t` text UI mode
- `-n`, `--non-interactive`, `--noninteractive`
                      Run without ever asking for user input. This may require additional command line flags; the client will try to explain which ones are required if it finds one missing

Comment: actually, it's better to use `-t` option for text mode, e.g.


`./letsencrypt-auto --apache  -m youremail@domain.com --agree-tos --redirect -t`

Comment: What exactly to set `TERM` to obviously depends on what sort of terminal you are running. `xterm` basically requires an X11 window or similar with GUI decorations; an example of a more traditional "modem line" type of terminal with wide support across terminal emulators is `vt220`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be issue with TERM or with 'dialog' software. Try to find it (which dialog) and update it. I've installed a new version of dialog and repplaced /usr/bin/dialog with /usr/local/bin/dialog (ln -s ... )

Comment: have you managed to get rid of `qqqqqq` and `x` (instead of normal lines) ?

Comment: @vitr, try to set up different/correct TERM variable.

Comment: `TERM=xterm` works